# Get an INPUT value from HTML Input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make this Guessing Game. Below is the repo on Github.
https://github.com/christsapphire/Guessing-Game

I wrote the logic in guessing-game.js and it worked fine.  Which I am using userGuess = prompt("Guess a number"). However, if I click cancel on this prompt, it will keep asking (maybe thats why??).

I tried to translate this to jQuery, using userGuess = $('#input').val(); and it encountered a bug. The webpage crashed after I click the "Submit" button.

I want when a user click "Submit" button on the webpage, it runs this function below.

```
function checkUserInput() {

    for (var valid = false; !valid;) {

        //I suspect these two  below
        // userGuess = parseInt($('#submit').val(), 10)
        //userGuess = parseInt(prompt("Guess a number"), 10);
       //-----------

        if ((userGuess >= 1) && (userGuess <= 100)) {
            if (repeatAnswer(userGuess, userGuessHistory)) {
                $('#status').text("You chose that number before! Choose another number!");
            } else {
                valid = true;

                userGuessHistory.push(userGuess);
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            $('#status').text("That number is invalid! Please enter a number between 1-100");
        }
    }

}
```

I think when I enable userGuess = $('#submit').val() it is repeatedly trying to take an input value from the Input html element, so it crashed.

Please help!  Thanks before

Comment: Describe what exactly you mean by "crash", and provide the full text of any error messages that occur.

Comment: __I want when a user click "Submit" button on the webpage, it runs this function below.__ Have you tried `$("#sumbit").click(checkUserInput);` ?

Comment: There was no error messages, just crashed like that.

Yes, I tried that, it still didn't work.  Maybe it has something to do with my FOR loop

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are really wanting to get the value of the input, not the submit button:

```
$("#input").val();
```

Are you trying to attach your function to the submit button?  That would be:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
     CheckUserInput();
});
```

Comment: No, thats not what I am trying to do.

Yes I already tried that, I want to attach that function to the submit button just like the way you suggested.